# Rails - max version with grouping

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Okay, I have searched for an answer but I keep getting stuck on this problem. I am trying to get the max version for a group of items. This is what I have working, and it grabs all the correct items but does not grab the latest version of them.

```
    def index
       @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])

       @items = Item.group(:original_id).where(original_id: ItemOriginal.select("id").where(:project_id => @project.id))
    end
```

A project has many ItemOriginals and ItemOriginals have many Items.

I anything I try with max version or last created_at only grabs one record and not a record for each ItemOriginal

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive, but I think you are asking, "Give me all this Project's ItemOriginals, and on each one include the version of its highest-versioned Item." In that case, this should work:

```
@items = @project.item_originals.select("item_originals.*, (SELECT MAX(version) FROM items i WHERE i.item_original_id = item_originals.id) AS max_version")
```

Then on each item you can get its `max_version`:

```
- @items.each do |item|
  = item.max_version
```

If you need the *whole* item and not just the version, you should switch to Postgres and use a `LATERAL JOIN`. :-)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I will see if I can get this working. I had something working with arrays but once I try and use the search method for the ransack gem it all broke..

Comment: Also the option of using Postgres is a no for my project unfortunately.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to work out the SQL before translating it into ActiveRecord. Getting the whole Item sounds a lot like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/25534279 and also see http://illuminatedcomputing.com/posts/2015/02/postgres_lateral_join/

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!